# How to count a many to many relationships and apply where clause with ORM Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to perform a findAll query that counts certain relationships and also filters for the minimum amount, with Sequelize ORM.
Let me explain, i have a Users table that has two M:N relationships with the Recipes table (specifically, there are 2 pivot tables: RecipeFavorites, RecipeStores), and a 1:M relationship with the Recipes table.

User model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'Users',
    timestamps: false
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {

    User.belongsToMany(models.Recipe, {
      through: 'RecipeStore',
      as: 'storedRecipes'
    });

    User.belongsToMany(models.Recipe, {
      through: 'RecipeFavorite',
      as: 'favoriteRecipes'
    });

    User.hasMany(models.Recipe, {
      as: 'createdRecipes',
      foreignKey: 'createdById'
    });

  };
  return User;
};
```

And is this the current query:

```
User
    .findAll({
        attributes: {
            exclude: ['password'],
            include: [
                'createdAt',
               [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("storedRecipes.id")), "countStoredRecipes"],
               [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("favoriteRecipes.id")), "countFavoriteRecipes"]
               [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("createdRecipes.id")), "countCreatedRecipes"]
            ],
        },
        group: ['id'],
        include: [
            {
                model: Recipe,
                as: 'createdRecipes',
                attributes: []
            },
            {
                model: Recipe,
                as: 'favoriteRecipes',
                attributes: []
            },
            {
                model: Recipe,
                as: 'storedRecipes',
                attributes: []
            }
        ],
        where: {
            countCreatedRecipes: {
                [Op.gte]: 1,
            },
            countFavoriteRecipes: {
                [Op.gte]: 3,
            },
            countStoredRecipes: {
                [Op.gte]: 2,
            }
    })
    .then(users => {
        return res.status(200).json({
            ok: true,
            users
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            error
        });
    });
```

However it does not work.

I hope the query returns something like:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "email1@email.com",
            "countStoredRecipes": 10,
            "countFavoriteRecipes": 3,
            "countCreatedRecipes": 9
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "email": "email5@email.com",
            "countStoredRecipes": 10,
            "countFavoriteRecipes": 4,
            "countCreatedRecipes": 9
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "email7@email.com",
            "countStoredRecipes": 2,
            "countFavoriteRecipes": 8,
            "countCreatedRecipes": 7
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have used `sequelize.literal()` instead of `sequelize.fn()` to count, and having instead of where. The result is as follows:

```
User.findAll({
  attributes: {
    exclude: ["password"],
    include: [
      "createdAt",
      [
        sequelize.literal(
        '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RecipeStores WHERE RecipeStores.userId = User.id)'),
        'countStoredRecipes'
      ],
      [
        sequelize.literal(
        '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RecipeFavorites WHERE RecipeFavorites.userId = User.id)'),
        'countFavoriteRecipes'
      ],
      [
        sequelize.literal(
        '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Recipes WHERE Recipes.createdById = User.id)'), 
        'countCreatedRecipes'
      ],
    ],
  },
  group: ["id"],
  having: {
    countStoredRecipes: {
      [Op.gte]: 2,
    },
    countCreatedRecipes: {
      [Op.gte]: 1,
    },
    countFavoriteRecipes: {
      [Op.gte]: 3,
    },
    
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `required: false` to your includes to make them a LEFT JOIN and still return results when there is no match. To filter by a derived value like COUNT you need to use a `having` clause, not `where`.

```js
User.findAll({
  attributes: {
    exclude: ["password"], // this should be a hash not an actual password
    include: [
      "createdAt",
      [
        sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("storedRecipes.id")),
        "countStoredRecipes",
      ],
      [
        sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("favoriteRecipes.id")),
        "countFavoriteRecipes",
      ][
        (sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("createdRecipes.id")),
        "countCreatedRecipes")
      ],
    ],
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: Recipe,
      as: "createdRecipes",
      attributes: [],
      required: false,
    },
    {
      model: Recipe,
      as: "favoriteRecipes",
      attributes: [],
      required: false,
    },
    {
      model: Recipe,
      as: "storedRecipes",
      attributes: [],
      required: false,
    },
  ],
  group: ["id"],
  having: {
    countCreatedRecipes: {
      [Op.gte]: 1,
    },
    countFavoriteRecipes: {
      [Op.gte]: 3,
    },
    countStoredRecipes: {
      [Op.gte]: 2,
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The response format "works", but the relationships data it's wrong. If I remove the 'having' part, it returns data in sequence: 6,5,4..3 in all counts

Comment: You might not be able to use the alias in the having clause, try to create it with `sequelize.where()`